# UIView height doesn't decrease even by changing the frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am having two types of cells in my UITableView - commonCell and expandedCell. Expanded cell expands on tap showing full description and the label adjusts itself accordingly, i.e., the label height is dynamic.
[UITableView snapshot showing cell with attachment opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6SR.png)

All of the below code is written inside - tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:  for the expanded cell :

```
     // Debug area log before changing frame

     //Printing description of viewAttachment: 
     //UIView: 0x7f8f84d8b050; frame = (16 107; 288 20); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 314; layer = CALayer: 0x7f8f84d7a340

    CGFloat height =[[HSHelper sharedInstance]  getLabelSizeFortext:help.helpDescription forWidth:labelDescText.frame.size.width                                                                        WithFont:kFontRobotoRegular(15).height;
    height = (height<20.0)? 20.0 + 20: height + 10;

    CGFloat heightAttachment = 0.0;
    if (help.helpAttachmentName.length != 0) {
        heightAttachment = [HSHelper sharedInstance].isiPad ? 35.0 :20.0;
    } else {
        CGRect framee = viewAttachment.frame;
        framee.size.height = 0.0f;
        viewAttachment.frame = framee;
    }

    // Debug area log after changing frame

    //Printing description of viewAttachment: 
    //UIView: 0x7f8f84d8b050; frame = (16 107; 288 0); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 314; layer = CALayer: 0x7f8f84d7a340

    return height + 23.0 + heightAttachment + 34.0;
```

The image display the problem :
[UITableView snapshot showing cell without attachment opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJFMq.png)

As you can see in my code the commented portion shows the result printed in my Debug area which clearly displays that the height of viewAttachment has been changed. But still, the simulator snapshot image shows the blank area where no file has been attached which should collapse.

I have also set the height of the viewAttachment to ‘<=‘ rather than ‘=‘ in the storyboard.

Please help me with this weird problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you reload table after this?

Comment: Of course @Nitin. I have already tried that.

Comment: log shows frame as (16 107; 288 0). means height is 0.

Answer (score -1):

try to set

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but what happens is that the viewAttachment collapses fine but along with that the top and bottom constraint for it. This results in the description label moving straight down to the cell bottom.   :-(

Comment: add  top,bottom,left,right  Constraint and don't add height constraint  to lable

Comment: I have not added any height constraint to the lable since its dynamic. Height constraint for viewAttachment is given with '<='.